# window.location.reload with Firefox not works (Facebook Javascript SDK)

Tags: facebook, firefox, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

i created an app for Facebook and i am using the Facebook PHP SDK with Javascript SDK.

My problem is, that after i click on the login button Firefox doesn't reload the page but its giving the message to confirm action to reload. After confirming nothing happens, i must manually reload the page. 
Same problem with Internet Explorer. *Only Chrome works absolutely fine.* 
I searched heavily on google and the root of the problem is the window.location.reload() function.

I tried towrap the function in settimeout(see below) but it doesn't worked.

My Base Code is the the slightly **changed** Facebook Example from: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/examples/with_js_sdk.php

--->> I Wonder myself why the Facebook guys upload code that defintely doesnt run properly with Firefox and IE.

My used code is:

```
<?php


    include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/config/config.php");
    include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/config/facebook_config.php");
    include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/config/connection.php");



// See if there is a user from a cookie
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    echo '<pre>'.htmlspecialchars(print_r($e, true)).'</pre>';
    $user = null;
  }
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <body>
    <?php if ($user) { ?>
      Your user profile is
      <pre>
        <?php print htmlspecialchars(print_r($user_profile, true)) ?>
      </pre>
    <?php } else { ?>
      <fb:login-button></fb:login-button>
    <?php } ?>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId: '<?php echo $facebook->getAppID() ?>',
          cookie: true,
          xfbml: true,
          oauth: true
        });
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
          setTimeout('window.location.reload()',0);
        });
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
          setTimeout('window.location.reload()',0);
        });
      };
      (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol +
          '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
      }());
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Still having the "reload" problem with Firefox and Internet Explorer

Comment: You are you setting a timeout with 0? This does not make much sense. Beside the first argument of setTimeout needs to be a callback, not a function call. Try it without the setTimeout and call ...reload() directoy inside the subscription.

Comment: i tried it directly with window.location.reload() but it didn't work